# Modelica and SIMULINK yield completely different results

Tags: matlab, openmodelica

I'm trying to simulate a 1D model of two bodies sliding on each other with a Coulomb friction in between.

[image]

As I have explained [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/348240/modeling-static-coulomb-friction-in-a-multibody-system/348254#348254) I modeled the friction as :

1. The force required to keep two bodies adhered $F_{a12}=\frac{m_2F_1-m_1F_2}{m_1+m_2}$
2. kinetic friction force $F_{f_k12}=Sign\left(v_1-v_2\right)\mu_k F_{n12}$
3. maximum static friction $F_{f_s12}=\mu_s F_{n12} $
4. $F_{f12}=\left\{\begin{matrix}
     if \, v_1=v_2 \, and \, \left| F_{a12} \right|<F_{f_s12} \,\, then &  F_{a12} \\
     else &  F_{f_k12}
    \end{matrix}\right.$

Considering the values as $\mu_s=0.3$, $\mu_k=0.2$, $F_{n12}=3$, $m_1=1$, $m_2=2$, $F_1=2\sin(5t)$, $F_2=2\sin(7t)$ I implemented the model in modelica language as:

```
model friction
  //constants
  parameter Real muk = 0.2;
  parameter Real mus = 0.3;
  parameter Real m1 = 1.0;
  parameter Real m2 = 2.0;
  parameter Real Fn12 = 3.0;
  parameter Real absTol = 0.1;
  //variables
  Real X1, X2, V1, V2, A1, A2, F1, F2, Ff12, Fs12;

initial equation
  X1 = 0;
  X2 = 0;

  V1 = 0;
  V2 = 0;

equation
  F1 = 2*sin(5 * time);
  F2 = 2*sin(7 * time);

  V1 = der(X1);
  V2 = der(X2);

  A1 = der(V1);
  A2 = der(V2);

  m1 * A1 = F1 - Ff12;
  m2 * A2 = F2 + Ff12;



  Fs12=(m2*F1-m1*F2)/(m1+m2);


  if abs(V1 - V2) < absTol and abs(Fs12) < mus * Fn12 then
    Ff12=Fs12;
  else
    Ff12 = muk * Fn12 * sign(V1 - V2);
  end if;


end friction;
```

and this is the result for $x_1$ and $x_2$:

[image]

and I modeled the exact same thing in SIMULINK ([download the .slx model here](https://ufile.io/1gu10)) and there is a completely different result:
[image]

Why am I getting two completely different results?! Am I doing a mistake in implementation or the difference is due to the different solvers these two programs use? Which one should I trust in that case?!

P.S. I just realized that there is something wrong with Wolfram SystemModeler solver. When I do the simulation in OponModelica the result is more similar.

Comment: Are you using the same time steps? I have a feeling your modelica model is overshooting due to a too large time step. Simulink uses ode45 I believe by default which has adaptative time stepping.

Comment: @BlaB I just used the default settings. how/where I can change the time step? and what value is compatible with the one in ode45?

Comment: I do not know sorry, this is very software specific regretfully...

Comment: @BlaB do you think that I should have asked this question somewhere else? which SO community is better for this question do you think?

Comment: I would assume that this is user error far before assuming this is a software error. Make sure it's actually the same, and solve at low tolerances to make sure each integrator is fairly exact.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas what do you mean by low tolerance?

Comment: Set the absolute and relative tolerances to small numbers.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas sorry noob here. Where should I set these values?

Comment: Look at the software documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch solver to `CVODES` or tighten the tolerance to 1e^-8.
[image]

Performing one of those changes results in this:
[image]

Comment: Increasing the negative exponent is decreasing the tolerance.

Comment: Yeah probably would have been better to call it tightening the tolerance.